# git - How to checkout files from another branch based on diff-filter?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff

Let's say I want to checkout all the files from another branch that are missing from my current branch.

I know I can find these files by doing a `git diff OTHER-BRANCH diff-filter=D` because all files considered deleted are ones that my current branch is missing.

Is there a way to do a `git checkout OTHER-BRANCH --diff-filter=D` of some sort? Or perhaps you have to pipe all the files from the `git diff` into a `git checkout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff <BRANCH-NAME> --diff-filter=D --name-only --exit-code | xargs git checkout <BRANCH-NAME>
```

Use the `-0` flag (`xargs -0`) for complicated file names.
*It goes without saying that you should back up before testing new git commands.*

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly! I fixed your command though -- you need to do `git checkout <BRANCH-NAME>` at the end otherwise it tries to checkout those files from the current branch you are on which you do not have.

Comment: @aug Nice. Using my iPad so I couldn't test it. Glad it worked out!